# How do I have control over the pipe created by popen()?

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe, popen

**Note:** I know I can achieve what I am describing by using `fork` and maybe `wait` but I want to understand how `popen` works and how I can use it to communicate between processes.

I want to use `popen` to create a child process, then in the child process I write to the pipe created by `popen` and then, in the parent process, I read from the pipe and output the message.

This is what I have tried:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 105

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    int status;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    fp = popen("date", "r"); // returns `FILE *` object (the same as a "stream", I think)
    if(fp == NULL) { printf("Eroare la deschidere cu `popen()`\n");} return -1; // or `EXIT_FAILURE`

    fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp); // ????? is this where I am reading from the pipe? 
                                    // `popen` returns a pointer to a stream, thus is it a `FILE *` object?
                                    // As such, is `fp` also the pipe? "pipe" == "stream" == `FILE *` object ?
    printf("I have read: %s", buffer); 

    status = pclose(fp);
    if(status == -1) { printf("`Eroare la inchiderea cu popen()`\n"); return -1;} // or `EXIT_FAILURE`

return 0; // or `EXIT_SUCCESS`?
}
```

Also, which is the pipe in such a context? Is `fp` both a `FILE *` object and "the pipe"? Can I access `fp[0]` & `fp[1]` ?

**Output:**

```
I have read: Thu Apr 30 16:29:05 EEST 2020
```

Comment: `popen` is a standard C function. It has nothing to do with processes or Unix pipes or `<unistd.h>` or `<sys/types.h>` or `<sys/wait.h>`. Internally it may or may not be implemented using these Unix facilities. If it is, it hides them from the programmer completely.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Hi and thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking here, so let me know if this answer misses the mark.

`man popen` confirms that popen returns a `FILE *`. It's not an array; there is no `fp[0]` or `fp[1]`.

A "pipe" is just a pair of connected file descriptors...one is available in the parent process (that's the return value from popen) and one is available in the child process. When you read from your `fp` variable you are reading from one end of the pipe (and when the child process writes to `stdout` it is writing to the other end of the pipe).

> is the child reading from the stream or the parent

When you run `fp = popen("date", "r")`,  you are creating a uni-directional pipe. The parent can read, and the child can write (if you were to specify `"w"` as the mode instead you'd have the opposite).

You are explicitly reading from the pip here:

```
fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
```

> and how do I know what is executed by the sub-process

The subprocess executes what you told it to (in this case, `date`).

> Furthermore, how do we know which end is for read and which is for write

You control with the second argument to the `popen` command.

---

> is the whole purpose of popen (in my case, here) to redirect the output of a command to the parent process

The purpose of `popen` is to permit communication between a child process and a parent process. It creates a unidirectional pipe, but you control whether that is `parent -> child` or `child -> parent`.

> Is this what happens in the program I have provided? 1) popen opens a sub-process 2) The sub-process writes the output of the date command to the writing-end of the pipe 3) The parent process reads the read-end of the pipe(ie what the child has transmitted)?

That is correct.

Comment: Hi! And thank you for your answer! No, you are not missing the mark here. I was not sure of the following thing; when I am reading from `fp`: is the child reading from the stream or the parent and how do I know what is executed by the sub-process and what is executed by the parent process when dealing with `popen` ? Furthermore, how do we know which end is for *read* and which is for *write*; when using `popen`, is it always that the child writes back to the parent?

Comment: Judging by everything I had already found on the internet and your answer: is the whole purpose of `popen` (in my case, here) to redirect the output of a command to the parent process, which reads it (from the pipe)? Is this what happens in the program I have provided? 1) `popen` opens a sub-process 2) The sub-process writes the output of the `date` command to the *writing-end* of the pipe 3) The parent process reads the *read-end* of the pipe(ie what the child has transmitted)?I think it is all clear, now. Nevertheless, feel free to add any other remarks if you think they would be useful.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some responses to your comments.

Comment: Very meatly explained! Everything is much clearer, now. Thank you so much! And good luck!